# Automating TortoiseSVN and Not to show Log Windows?

Tags: svn, automation, tortoisesvn

Is there any parameter for Automating `TortoiseSVN` and Not to show Log Windows?

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseSVN is a GUI client and is not meant to be used in this way. If you don't want a GUI, don't use a GUI - use the command-line client (bundled with TortoiseSVN 1.7 and newer installers), or use the client libraries/language bindings for your language/scripting environment of choice.